# Why SORTUPBY return wrong value in IBM ITX?

Tags: websphere, wtx

This is the maprule:

```
=SORTUPBY(FF1(Mission:In1),manufacturerCount:Mission:In1)
```

syntactically it is ok.

This is the input:

```json
[{"mission_name":"Thaicom","manufacturers":["A"]},{"mission_name":"Thaicom-2","manufacturers":["A","B"]}]
```

This is the output:

```
[{"mission_name":""},]
```

Expected output is:

```json
[{"mission_name":"Thaicom-2","manufacturers":["A","B"]},{"mission_name":"Thaicom","manufacturers":["A"]}]
```

[image]